# The :as attribute in my root line in config/routes.rb is messing up my application. What's wrong with it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a model and controller called coves_controller. I have this line in my routes.rb file right now: root :to => 'coves#index', :as => 'coves'

When I comment it out and go to localhost:3000/coves, everything works fine. When I uncomment it, I'm unable to create a new cove object.. There is no error statement, it just doesn't add to the database.

When I change 'coves' to 'cove' at the end, I'm can create new cove objects, but after doing so I'm routed to coves/.5 which should be coves/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there is a conflict with the paths created by:

```
 resources :coves
```

That is basic REST behaviour.

Don't add a 'as' statement for you root, root is just root :)

Comment: Edited to take into account the excellent remark of @idlefingers. +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

If you look at [how the root path is defined](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L255), it's just a convenience method which creates a named route for you. The `reverse_merge` method used to load in the options means that your `:as => 'coves'` part of the hash will be getting ignored and changed back to `:as => :root`. You cannot rename the root path when using the `root` method.

As @apneadiving said, you need to use `resources :coves` to get RESTful CRUD routes for it.